# How do register the callback for process when exit in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I create process in Linux and I need to register the callback when the process exits? What's the proper way to go?
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [std::atexit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit), and an example stolen from cppreference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void atexit_handler_1() 
{
    std::cout << "at exit #1\n";
}

void atexit_handler_2() 
{
    std::cout << "at exit #2\n";
}

int main() 
{
    const int result_1 = std::atexit(atexit_handler_1);
    const int result_2 = std::atexit(atexit_handler_2);

    if ((result_1 != 0) or (result_2 != 0)) {
        std::cerr << "Registration failed\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "returning from main\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This problem is my program must to manage many processes (
In other words is manage many file .exe). Each process I want to register one callback for this. Is there another way?

Comment: Suppose that you could use fork/exec to create new process. In main(parent) process, you could catch **SIGCHILD** signal and do cleanup operation.

Comment: @Jacky1205 Could you clarify what the cleanup operation would be? How does the SIGCHILD call back function know which child process resulted in the SIGCHILD call?

Comment: @Sanket_Diwale You could call `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)` which returns the pid of child process, see https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid for more details.

Comment: You could also read these two nice books, `Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment`, chapter 10 or `Computer System: A programmer's Perspective`, chapter 8